# DoctrineのQueryBuilderでORDER BY Fieldを使用したい

Tags: php, doctrine2

doctrineで以下のような形でデータを取得しています。
$partsNoArrayはINT型の配列、$owner_noはINT型です。

```
    $PartsArray = $PartsRepository->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->add('where', $expr->andX(
                            $expr->eq('p.owner_no', '?1'),
                            $expr->in('p.parts_no', '?2')
                        ))
                    ->setParameters(array(
                        1 => $owner_no,
                        2 => $partsNoArray
                    ))
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
```

この取得処理中に`ORDER BY field(p.parts_no,$partsNoArray)`のようなコードを挿入して
$partsNoArrayの配列の順序通りにデータを取得することは可能でしょうか？

ややこしい質問とは思いますが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

英語版stackoverflowに、Doctrine2でMySQLのField関数をつかったORDER BYについて質問／回答がありました。

- [Doctrine 2 mysql FIELD function in order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957330/doctrine-2-mysql-field-function-in-order-by)

上記ページのpolianychさんの回答と、それにつけられたMr Hashさんのコメントを合わせて、設定等補足すると以下のようになります。

### Field関数を使えるようエクステンションを有効にする

- https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions
- packagist では [beberlei/DoctrineExtensions](https://packagist.org/packages/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions)

beberlei/DoctrineExtensionsはstableリリースがないので、インストールする場合は次のようにdev-masterを指定します。

```
$ composer require beberlei/DoctrineExtensions:dev-master
```

### カスタム関数を登録する

Doctrineを直接使っている場合は、

```
$doctrineConfig = $this->em->getConfiguration();
$doctrineConfig->addCustomStringFunction('FIELD', 'DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Field');
```

とします（[Doctrineのマニュアル](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html)）。

Symfonyを使っている場合は、コンフィギュレーションファイルで

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        # ...
        dql:
            string_functions:
                FIELD: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Field
```

と記述すれば利用できます（[Symfonyのマニュアル](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html)）。

### QueryBuilder内の記述

```
$qb
    ->select("r, field(r.id, :ids) as HIDDEN field")
    ->from("Entities\Round", "r")
    ->where("r.id IN :ids")
    ->setParameter('ids', $ids)
    ->orderBy("field");
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！

以下のコードで取得することができました。
`
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$PartsArray = $qb->select('p, field(p.parts_no, :ids) as HIDDEN field')
            ->from('Entities\Parts\Parts', 'p')
           ->where($expr->andX(
                    $expr->eq('p.owner_no', '?1'),
                    $expr->in('p.parts_no', '?2')
            ))
            ->setParameters(array(
                    1 => $this->owner_no,
                    2 => $partsNoArray,
                    'ids' => $partsArray
            ))
            ->orderBy("field")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
`